# Can Maven's provided scoping, be transitive?

Tags: maven, dependencies

I have an Ancestor dependency has dependent scoped as provided, I need to propagate that scoping to anything that depends on my project.

For example, say I have `SomeProjectA` which depends on `SomeLibraryB`. I need to scope `SomeLibraryB` has provided.

Currently to compile anything that depends on `SomeProjectA`, has to also set `SomeLibraryB` has provided. I would rather propagate that scoping, then have any project that depend on mine deal with my project's dependents..

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I dont think that is possible. Each project should declare provided dependencies on its own. Propagating that scope would be wrong since you would make an assumption about the deployment that you cant make since you are not responsible for the deployment. The user of your library does that..

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. That's what I thought, just wanted to be sure that I had not gotten myself confused. The problem is that one of my dependents needs to be shadowed because the platform I'm deploying to provides a older version.

Comment: Be careful when falling back to older versions. There might be incompatibilities..

Answer (score 0):

### Simple hack

This can be achieved by a simple hack.

[image]

You can exclude `SomeLibraryB` and `SomeLibraryC` inside your direct dependency tag.

*Below is the dependency tag for your `SomeProjectA`.*

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.direct.dependency</groupId>
        <artifactId>SomeProjectA</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.some</groupId>
                <artifactId>SomeLibraryB</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.some</groupId>
                <artifactId>SomeLibraryC</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

But if you have this configuration, your tests and compilation other validations will starts to fail. Therefore, you can put direct dependencies to those libraries with **`<scope>test</scope>`**.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>SomeLibraryB</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.some</groupId>
        <artifactId>SomeLibraryC</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: No, why using test scope which is also not transitive, whereas we can define provided scope ? This is confusing.

Answer (score -1):

As you can see from the [Maven documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html), the *provided* scope doesn't influence compilation, but runtime. In general you should only need to specify the provided scope in the dependencies for a packaging project, such as a project of type *war*. For this reason it doesn't usually matter much that it isn't transitive.

In other words, if you add a dependency to a `jar` project without explicitly specifying its scope, that dependency will be made available during compilation and so will that dependency's dependencies. If you then explicitly declare that dependency to have provided scope, this does not change.

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. The provided scope does influence compilation, but leaves the dependencies out when packaging the project (for example in a war). It actually also does matter that it's not transitive, if it would be transitive then all the transitive dependencies would be added to the compile classpath and your module could use all of these dependencies for compiling. This would then mean that your dependency has implicit compile time dependencies which is a _bad thing_.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what I wrote is correct. Setting a dependency to *provided* is not different from the default, which is *compile*, where compilation is concerned. Implicit dependencies *are* added to the compile classpath, whether they are defined as *compile* or as *privided*. Provided dependencies are not added to the runtime path, but this effect is not recursive. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: The solution to our disagreement is on that page: "This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive." The fact that it is not transitive means that transitive dependencies are _not_ brought in a compile time. Since the dependencies are excluded at runtime, transitive or not does not matter for runtime. Given this, your statement about recursion does not make sense to me.

Comment: Granted, I think I read this part of your original answer: "the provided scope doesn't influence compilation, but runtime." a bit too literally, without reading the rest. It sounded like you thought that a provided dependency didn't end up on the compile classpath, but clearly you didn't think that. Either way, none of this is helping in solving Nicholas' problem.. :)

Comment: (After reading the comments) I get that you compared provided to compile, but I'm still downvoting because the answer is poorly worded and misleading.  Also the "In general..." statement is overreaching.

Comment: Your choice. At least you explained your motivation. I fail to see how my answer is "poorly worded", given the average here on Stack Overflow, and even less how it is misleading, as it corrects a mistaken assumption in the original question. As to the "In general..." statement I notice you do not provide a counter example. You're entitled to your opinions, but I stand by everything I wrote.

Comment: (After reading the comments) answer is poorly worded. First, `provided` influence compilation. Second, concept that provided should be used only by WAR goes too far. That approach solves provided-no-transitive issue, but it cost WAR configuration complexity. JAR config is simpler, WAR config is more complex. If you have to manage multiple WARs you prefer JAR which don't need extra "provided" configuration

Comment: You are wrong. Add or remove the `provided` scope to a dependency in a jar's pom and you'll see that it compiles in exactly the same way. Moreover `provided` influences packaging, not compilation, so it makes no sense to use it in a pom that doesn't perform any packaging. By the way I never wrote that provided should be *only* used in war pom's.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti, you wrote "In general you should only". I made a short cut to "only" because comment has a limited length. Regardless of "only" or "in general only", approach that `provided` applies for packaging project may or may not suit concrete case and cannot be treated as recommended approach.

Comment: You still are mistaken. If you add a dependency to a pom with the default `compile` scope that dependency is made available during compilation, during test and, if that project contains a packaging step, that dependency is packaged together with the other dependencies. If you change the dependency to `provided` it is still available for compilation and testing, but it is not included when packaging. This is how Maven works. You can do whatever you like but this won't change.

Comment: @NicolaMusatti, when you ADD artifact with scope `provided`, it is visible for compilantion but not included in WAR. In other words it influences compilation and not influence packaging. As far as I follow you, when you CHANGE scope from `compile` to `provided` the compilation is not impacted but packaging is impacted. I still think you answer is poorly worder now, but if you clarify that you mean change from `compile` to `provided` then it will became more clear