# Tomcat 8 + Maven + Java EE 7 Web Profile

Tags: java, maven, java-ee-7, eclipse-luna, tomcat8

I'm trying to use Tomcat 8 as the server for a new web application. I'm going to use a lot of the java EE 7 web profile technologies, among them, the EJB Lite specification.

The web app project consists, in fact, of several other maven projects. I have a rest-api project (which uses JAX-RS 2.0), a business project (currently packaged as a jar) and domain project (also a jar). I have some set of common dependencies, which i packaged in a separate module "common-deps" (pom package). Among theses dependencies, is the java ee 7 web profile specification. All the other projects depend on the "common-deps" project.

Next is the pom.xml for the common-deps project:

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org /2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

      <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
      <groupId>....</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-deps</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
      <packaging>pom</packaging>
      <name>Common dependencies</name>

      <properties>
        <cdi.version>1.1</cdi.version>
        <sl4j.version>1.7.7</sl4j.version>
        <log4j.version>1.2.17</log4j.version>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
      </properties>

      <dependencies>

      <dependency> 
           <groupId>javax</groupId>   
            <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>   
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope> 
      </dependency> 
  <!--  
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>${cdi.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency> 
  -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${sl4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>junit</groupId>
         <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
         <version>${junit.version}</version>
         <scope>test</scope>
     </dependency>
  </dependencies>

</project>
```

The thing is that when i try to create a stateless session bean with the @Stateless annotation, this annotation is not found. I don't know why is this, perhaps the javaee-web-api scope shouldn't be provided? But, as far as i understand, tomcat 8 should support this profile... perhaps it is because i'm missing a concrete implementation of some of the java ee apis? If this is indeed the case, should i specify the implementation for every api inside the java ee web profile? And, what implementation should i choose for the ejb lite api?

I searched everywhere but i could not find any tutorial about developing a java ee 7 web app with tomcat 8, and as i'm new to the java ee stack (coming from Spring) i must be doing something wrong. I'm using Eclipse Luna as IDE.

Excuse my poor english!

Comment: tomcat is only web container, it doesn't support Web Profile out of the box. If you are interesting in building apps with Java EE web profile ready server, I'd recommend to take a look at WebSphere Liberty. It is already Java EE 6 web profile certified (so no jar/dependency nightmare), and has already many most useful features from Java EE 7 web profile, with more to come. Check it out - https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/ free for development. There is also tools plugin for Eclipse - WebSphere Developer Tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i understand now what's happening. It appears that dependencies with provided scope can't be transitive, which is exactly what i was hoping! ([Can Maven's provided scoping, be transitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793606/can-mavens-provided-scoping-be-transitive))

Thanks anyway!!